# When doing live plotting, is it possible to restart the plot without closing the program?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I am using Python's Matplotlib library to plot live data, which is acquired every second from a lab device. Here is the code I wrote for that, using random numbers instead of the signal acquired from the device:

```
from time import time, sleep
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from random import random

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
tList = [0] 
sList = [0] 
startTime = time()

try:
   
    print("MEASUREMENT STARTED\n")
    print("time (s)", "signal (V)", sep="\t")

    while True:

        signal = random()
        sList.append(signal)
        
        instant = float(time() - startTime)
        tList.append(instant)
        print(round(instant, 2), round(signal, 2), sep="\t")
     
        ax1.plot(tList, sList, color='blue', ls="-", linewidth=1.2, alpha=0.8)  
        ax1.set_xlabel('t (s)')
        ax1.set_ylabel('signal (V)', color = 'blue')
    
        plt.pause(0.001)
        sleep(1)
                
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    print("\nMEASUREMENT ENDED")

input("\n(Press Enter to exit)")
```

The problem I have is that I have to run this program for long periods of time (hours) and, as time progresses, the program slows down (I guess due to the increasingly heavy lists used and the consequent overloading of the computer's RAM). Also, sometimes I want to restart the plot just to reset the scaling. But if I close the program, I lose points while restarting the program.

Would it be possible to modify the code so that, when I press for example the Enter key, the plot is restarted?